# Fix broken links to Dwarf Fortress wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

There are [112 posts with a broken link to df.magmawiki.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Adf.magmawiki.com). This can be fixed by replacing the url with `dwarffortresswiki.org` and keeping the path unchanged.

Per [master meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/566903), this may be a candidate for the staff mass editing tool. If not, well, community edits welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The links have been replaced. I spot-checked a few and everything appears to be in order, but please shout if you see any weirdness.